# How to quickly populate a dictionary in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift

I'm creating a new dictionary, say:

```
var a: [Int: Int] = []
```

And, I'd like to set the keys `0...n` to `1`.

I'm doing this, rather brutishly as:

```
for i in 0...n {
    a[i] = 1
}
```

`n` is likely to be around 700000.  And, this "initialization" takes hours.

I know I can do this to an array:

```
var z: [Int] = []
z = Array(0...700000)
```

and, in a few seconds I get a 700000 element array.

What's the right way to populate my dictionary? Thanks much.

Comment: Does it help if you allocate the dictionary with the needed capacity: `var a = [Int: Int](minimumCapacity: 700000)` ?

Comment: It cuts the execution time by half on my computer (see my answer below). But my times are in seconds in both cases. Something weird with OP's environment, I think...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to run your code, slightly modified, like this:

```
let n = 700000
let start = NSDate()
var a: [Int: Int] = [:] //Dictionary<Int, Int>(minimumCapacity: n)

for i in 0..<n {
    a[i] = 1
}
let stop = NSDate()
let dif = stop.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
println(dif)
```

This runs for 6.7 seconds. If I replace the

```
[:]
```

with

```
Dictionary<Int, Int>(minimumCapacity: n)
```

it gets initialized in 3 seconds (debug build, no optimizations). Perhaps you are not on the latest build of Xcode?

Comment: Please note that my test is NOT in Playground, but regular executable. Playground takes much longer.

Comment: Perhaps, it is a playground issue then.  I'll retract the question, thanks for your help.